# Kernel as client, User application as server using netlink

Tags: linux, sockets, linux-kernel, client-server, netlink

I want to establish connection between kernel module and user application with the kernel as a client. In other words, kernel will send message to the user app, wait for reply, receive reply, and then continue execution.

For example, inside kernel I will send message and then wait for reply.

```
// inside kernel
nlmsg_unicast();

wait_until_user_reply();

/* process reply */
/* continue execution.. */
```

while inside user,

```
while (1) {
   // inside user
   recvmsg();

   /* assembly reply.. */

   sendmsg();
}
```

however, what netlink protocol does is invoking a callback function every time user sends message. What I want is to make kernel wait for a reply from user, then continue the execution. Is waiting in a busy loop on a global variable which is updated inside callback function feasible? I tried but I think that's not a very good solution.

Can I do something like "sleep until a reply come". Can I put the kernel to sleep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this problem using wait_for_completion. It turns out that it wasn't that hard.

Comment: Ah great, someone has similiar issues. Could you share the code?

Comment: @user1252280 Unfortunately I can't share the code.. You can look in the documentation of wait_for_completion(). Basically, you just have to do init_completion() once, send the message, and then do wait_for_completion() or wait_for_completion_timeout() in the kernel. That's all.

Comment: can we have a clearer answer? I tried what I understood from that message however, it causes a General Protection Fault